# UIScrollView setContentSize wrong in iPad?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, cocos2d-iphone

I'm integrating UIScrollView in my games and I notice the setContentSize seems like having some problem when I goes from iPhone to iPad.

Basically I scale the contentSize based on how many contents I have in the UIScrollView

```
CGSize newContentSize = CGSizeMake(0.0f, totalContent * contentHeight);
[scrollView setContentSize: newContentSize];
```

This codes work on iPhone retina, but when it goes to iPad, the contentSize has gone larger.
I check the value and it is correct (because in iPad the resolution has been doubled) Problem
is when I try to scroll until the bottom, it will display a lot of empty spaces after the last content.

Does anyone know what happen to this?

EDIT:
The complete codes are as below, it's not a normal app, it's using cocos2d game engine

```
CCSprite* image = [mImageArray objectAtIndex: 0];
CGSize newContentSize = mScrollView.contentSize;
newContentSize.height = mImageArray.count * image.contentSize.height;
[mScrollView setContentSize: newContentSize];
```

Comment: How do you calculate totalContent and contentHeight? Code would be useful here.

Comment: okay, I've edited my question with the codes provided.

Comment: Are you completely sure that all images in mImageArray are not empty and updated?

Comment: Maybe those images are switched to blnk ones when you display the scroll content or their sizes change after you calculate the height, or not all of them are displayed.

Comment: You might also check UIEdgeInsets for scrollView as this may affect way of displaying scroll content

Comment: Already double check, the image sizes are correct.
All values in UIEdgeInsets are zero, so is fine.

Comment: and the image array contains xtimes the same image? (looks fishy :D)